# 3D portable camera with depth sensing for less than $100

Tags: scanner, 3d-scanner

I am looking for a camera that can scan 3D objects for use in 3D modeling programs like Blender. Requirements:

- SDK
- quality 3D scans
- portable, preferably wireless
- less than $100

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you have 2 options:

1. Hand-held 3D scanners (cost at least $300): Sense 3D scanner, Structure.io, Go!SCAN, Fuel3D. Should work out-of-the-box.
2. USB depth sensors (difficult to find < $100). These have a few limitations:

   - All don't come with an SDK that creates high quality polygon models from 3D pointcloud. You'll end up coding.
   - Do not contain an IMU (Inertial Measurement Unit) like , so models may be mis-aligned. (this is just a guess)
   - Not wireless

What you are asking hasn't hit the market yet. I'd definitely invest some more money and choose option #1.

Answer (score 1):

It will be hard to find a stereo camera for < 100USD. Still, you can have a look on [Microsoft Kinect](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/kinect) and [Asus Xtion PRO LIVE](https://www.asus.com/3D-Sensor/Xtion_PRO_LIVE/).

There is no such stereo camera with a wireless video transmission in the market however you can make one using IEEE 802.11 transmission bands.

Comment: Xtion is discontinued after Primesense was acquired by Apple. MS Kinect v2 is probably the most accurate 3D sensor in the market, with a price tag of $150 + $50 for a PC adapter.