# 3D portable camera with depth sensing

Tags: camera, 3d-scanner

I know a similar question [is there](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/74/3d-portable-camera-with-depth-sensing-for-less-than-100) but it was asked 4 years ago and the market has changed significantly. 
Now I'm looking for a small wireless camera (maybe as small as phones' cameras). I found [this one](https://store.intelrealsense.com/buy-intel-realsense-depth-camera-sr305.html) but still big for my purpose, is there any smaller ones?